# (Java) Varying which object is modified

Tags: java

I'm sorry if this is a very obvious question, I guess I simply don't know the proper vocabulary to use to find the answer. My question is: Say I instantiate several objects, and each object has a unique integer that serves as its ID, and I want the user to be able to choose which object to modify by entering the object's ID. How should I go about that?

```
int ID;

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
Object obj1 = new Object(9897);
Object obj2 = new Object(2817);

System.out.println("Input the ID of the object you wish to modify:");
ID = keyboard.nextInt();
```

Assume I have a class written so that the objects instantiated in the previous code have their IDs equal to the argument passed to the constructors. Now say in the next line of code I want to change either object 1 or object 2 depending on whether the user inputs 9897 or 2817. How would I go about doing that without using a ton of if statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: you don't. Change your approach, put your instances in a `Map<Integer, Object>` and then you can look them up by ID.

```
Map<Integer, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(9897, new Object());
map.put(2817, new Object());

// ...
int ID = keyboard.nextInt();
Object obj = map.get(ID);
```